# Test list of proxy servers in R

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I have a list of proxy servers that I want to use with the `httr` and `rvest` packages. Something along the lines of:

```
x <- read_html(httr::GET("http://www.google.com",
                         use_proxy("111.22.333.444", 8080),
                         user_agent("httr"),
                         verbose()))
```

However, not all of the proxies on my list will connect. Is there a way to test these in advance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can load `httr` library and use `status_code()` to check the response status, if it's not 200, the proxy may not work.

Comment: Thanks @Yifu. Can you give an example?

Comment: Network issues are hard to replicate. Usually, if a proxy doesn't work, it will return an error. You can also tryCatch that error.

Comment: I was looking for a code snippet, demonstrating how you would use `status_code()` with `httr` to check teh response status.